# Completely locked out of Ubuntu Gnome 16.04, login loop

Tags: gnome, login, password

So I havent used my computer for a few days but today I turned it on and I have dual boot with windows, I booted into Ubuntu. Then I get a login screen but when I enter my password, the screen goes black and then just reloads the login screen.

So I googled this and people suggest doing ctl+alt+ f2 and then apt-get install some things but when I do this, whatever command I try in the command line , it asks to enter my password. I enter the password and it tells me `login incorrect` !!!! I didn't change a thing since last using the computer. What on earth is going on ? I cant log in and I cant use the command line to figure out whats going on.

Comment: Make sure that the username you entered at the `login: ` prompt is your actual Linux username (usually all lowercase - like `jsmith`) rather than the "full name" that is shown on the GUI login screen

Comment: Check caplock  and numlock status.  Also if you have any flaky keys, that might be the problem.  A sticky shift key gave me fits for a while. Unlike the caplock, there is no visual evidence even in a gui login screen.

Comment: Yes, the login user name is all lower case and I am certain there are no keyboard hiccups. The really strange thing is that I am getting incorrect login when I try to do sudo from command line. This is a huge red flag for me, how on earth does that happen ?

Comment: So I realized that I wasnt logging into the command line properly, but when I finally logged in, I looked to see if there was problem with Xauthority file...turns out I dont even have one. Any clues there?